# 50% width bug Chrome Android - Hairline

Tags: android, google-chrome, width

Have a look on this jsfiddle with Chrome on Android:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ajtK/

```
#left{ width:50%;...}
#right{ width:50%, left:50%;...}
#back{backround:blue;}
```

2 divs with 50% width and a blue background. Only on Chrome on Android, there is a small line shining through(look at the picture).

[image: Chrome-Android]

It is also not working with px sizes!
There is no problem on any other browser...does anybody know something aubout this? Is this a bug?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug caused by absolute positioning not by width.
If you give body "margin:2px", the blue line goes to the surrounding edges.

I have filed a bug at http://crbug.com/224525